# Debugging push notifications when app is not running

Tags: ios, swift

I have push notifications working from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method in AppDelegate, but I can't seem to work out how to get them working when the app is not in a background state. I've found quite a few questions on here which explain what todo which I have attempted below.

I was going on the logic of recalling `didReceiveRemoteNotification` if there is data.

The problem is this does not work, and also I have no idea how to debug this as to get the app into the state where this would be called I loose logging.

```
if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
    print(remoteNotification)
    self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: remoteNotification)
}

// This method is working fine
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active) {
        print("active don't do anything")
    } else {
        let notif = JSON(userInfo)
        if notif["vc"] != nil {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("handleNotification", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean soon as i kill the app from the background xcode debugger stops. To get xcode debugger working again I need to run the app again, meaning I can never open the app from a notification? Or am i missing something?

Comment: If you (or the user) manually kill the app, it won't open again into a background state. If you want to debug it, just but the app into a background state instead of killing it

Comment: @Ollie but putting the app into a background state ends up in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. But this method already works. I need to test notifications from the state when the app is not running in background.

Comment: Sorry if i'm not explaining myself correctly.

Comment: If you want to debug the killed app, you can do the following (at least this is what I did in this case): put an `NSThread.sleep(10)` in the `appkicationDidFinishedLaunching...`, so when the app starts, you will have 10 seconds before anything happens. Then in Xcode, Debug->Attach to process -> YOUR_APP, and then you can set breakpoints after that (but logs not worked for me.)

Comment: @Ollie see using breakpoints while your app is active whether notifications do arrive or not